# android - animation with random picture

Tags: java, android, animation, graphics

I want my animation to start after picking an image out of a pool of pictures. I thought I could do that with a randomly picking switch, but then I get an error, because 'ball' cannot be resolved. I hope it's not entirely wrong, but i don't know how to fix it neither

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

    Random randLan = new Random();
    int imag = randLan.nextInt(4) + 1;

    int image = 0;
    switch (imag)
        {
        case 1:
            image = R.drawable.ballgel;
            BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballgel);
            break;

        case 2:
            image = R.drawable.ballgel;
            BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballbl);
            break;

        case 3:
            image = R.drawable.ballgel;
            BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballgrue);
            break;

        case 4:
            image = R.drawable.ballgel;
            BitmapDrawable ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballrot);
            break;
            }


    if (x<0) {
        x = this.getWidth()/2;
        y = this.getHeight()/3;
    } 

        else {
            x += xVelocity;

                if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                    boolean continueAnimation = false;
                }
        }

    c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

    if(continueAnimation) 
    {
        h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
    }   

    else {
            x = this.getWidth()-ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried `BitmapDrawable ball` outside your switch case ?

Comment: When i put it outside the switch case, what's the last part of `(R.drawable. ...);` then? That should be the variable, but I think it needs an explicit reference there, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put right at the beginning:

```
private BitmapDrawable ball;
```

Then you replace `BitmapDrawable ball` in the switch with `ball`.
like that, `ball` is initalized at the beginning and is specified in the switch.

I've done it for you:

```
private BitmapDrawable ball;

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {  

            Random randLan = new Random();
            int imag = randLan.nextInt(4) + 1;

            int image = 0;
            switch (imag)
                {
                case 1:
                    image = R.drawable.ballgel;
                    ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballgel);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    image = R.drawable.ballgel;
                    ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballbl);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    image = R.drawable.ballgel;
                    ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballgrue);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    image = R.drawable.ballgel;
                    ball = (BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ballrot);
                    break;
                    }


            if (x<0) {
                x = this.getWidth()/2;
                y = this.getHeight()/3;
            } 

                else {
                    x += xVelocity;

                        if ((x > this.getWidth() - ball.getBitmap().getWidth()) || (x < 0)) {
                            boolean continueAnimation = false;
                        }
                }

            c.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), x, y, null);  

            if(continueAnimation) 
            {
                h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);
            }   

            else {
                    x = this.getWidth()-ball.getBitmap().getWidth();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Well, it's not working, the errors are gone, but now the program crashes. Do you know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Put some images in your drawble
then create an xml file in your drawble name.xml
use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a"
   android:duration="1000"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/b"
    android:duration="1000"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/c"
    android:duration="1000"></item>
</animation-list>
```

after that in your mainactivity use this code:

```
iv= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frameanimation);
    animationDrawable=(AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.start();
```

Comment: And how do I make it pick randomly then?